# can some one point to me some source code sample(android opengl , opengl )about solar system

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to develop a simple solar system.can some one point to me some source code sample(android opengl , opengl )about solar system so that I could learn these source code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jdunwoody/AndroidSandpit/tree/master/SolarSystem

https://github.com/martinbudden/solarsystem

these links may help you to understand.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I have down load, but there is a few code in these file.

Comment: oh ok..hope it will help you that you can write some code...if answer was good to you, please raise and accept